# Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable Error when using Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, jax-rs, pom.xml

I'm getting the following error on my JAX-RS app

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable
```

I think I'm getting the error on this line

```
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

I have the following libraries on the libs folder

```
poi-5.2.2.jar
poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar
poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.2.jar
poi-scratchpad-5.2.2.jar
```

I'm running this application on Tomcat 9 on Java 11. Please advice to resolve this issue if possible

Comment: Could you please provide the full stacktrace ?

Comment: The `poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar` contains that class. A `NoClassDefFoundError` often occurs when a class was found on compile time but not on run time. So I suspect the  `poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar`  is not on class path while run time.